# QwtPolar Library error Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qwt, qwtpolar

I'm having a trouble with the QwtPolar library.

I'm using Qt 5.3 and I have Qwt 6.1 working properly.

I build the QwtPolar using:

```
qmake 
make
make install
```

When I try to run the QwtPolar examples, I get the following error:

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

I already read a lot of posts in the Qt Forum and stackoverflow, but I can't figure out what is happening and how to solve it.

Note: I read some things about mixing the debug and release mode, but I don't know what mode was used to build the Qwt and how to change it.

I will appreciate if someone can help me.

I'm using Windows 8.1.

Sorry for my english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by recompiling the qwtpolar library.

Comment: how? can you give more details?

Answer (score 1):

I've met the same error long ago. I'll try to repeat your problem on my machine, and in the meantime try this (one of these should help):

- Switch from Debug mode to Release mode (or vice-versa) and build;
- Disable "Shadow build" in the Project config tab and build;
- Rebuild the project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.


- In release mode I get the following error:
`QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice`
And in debug mode I get this:
`error: cannot find -lqwtpolard`


- I tried to disable "Shadow build", but I'm still getting the error.


- I tried "clean all" and rebuild the project, but nothing changed.

Comment: viddik13 I solved the problem by recompiling the qwtpolar.

I don't know what happened before, I think I did something wrong on the compilation step. Anyway, thanks for the help.